# Transfer state from component to component

Tags: reactjs

I have a functional component and I need to get state from the first component and transfer to the List component

```
    const BlogPage = () => {
    ....
    return(
       <WithCallbacks options={breeds} title='породу' />
        <List breed="" />
    )}
```

I need to get `this.state.selectedOptions` from WithCallBacks and transfer to `<List breed={selectedOptions}`

```
 export default class WithCallbacks extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          selectedOptions: []
        };
        ...
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
      }
    
    
      ...
    
      handleChange = (selectedOptions) => {
        this.setState({ selectedOptions });
      }
      render() {
        const selectedOption = this.state.selectedOptions;
        return (
          <div>
            {/* <pre>inputValue: "{this.state.inputValue}"</pre> */}
            <p>{this.state.selectedOptions.value}</p>
            <AsyncSelect
              cacheOptions
              loadOptions={this.loadOptions}
              defaultOptions={this.options}
              onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
              placeholder={`Введите ${this.props.title}`}
              value={selectedOption}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
        }
```

I can't use Redux because I have used Gatsby, How I can do this ?
https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-butterfly-e3x3m

Comment: you can just pass the state as prop to List component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [lift state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) from `WithCallbacks` to `BlogPage` and pass it as a prop to both components.

```
const BlogPage = () => {
    const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = React.useState("");

    return (
       <WithCallbacks 
            options={breeds} 
            title='породу'
            selectedOptions={selectedOptions}
            setSelectedOptions={setSelectedOptions}
        />
        <List breed="" selectedOptions={selectedOptions} />
    )}
}
```

In `WithCallback`, you can call `setSelectedOptions` that you passed as a prop:

```
handleChange = (selectedOptions) => {
    setSelectedOptions(selectedOptions);
};
```

Comment: Can u get more details, I'm a newbie?)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-butterfly-e3x3m help , please

Comment: Instead of storing the `selectedOptions` state in the `WithCallbacks` components, you store it on the parent `BlogPage` component, so you can also pass it to `List`. You pass `setSelectedOptions` as a prop to `WithCallbacks`. In `WithCallbacks`, you need to change `handleChange` to call `setSelectedOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const BlogPage = () => {
    ....
const [breed, setBreed] = useState("")
    return(
        />
      <WithCallbacks options={breeds.sort(compare)} title='породу'
        selectBreed={(hadleBreed) => setBreed(hadleBreed)} />
      {console.log(breed)}
      <List breed={breed} />
    )}


export default class WithCallbacks extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
              selectedOptions: []
            };
            ...
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
          }
          handleChange = (selectedOptions) => {
        this.setState({ selectedOptions });
        this.props.selectBreed(selectedOptions.value)
      }
        
          ...
```